# Can iOS UIWebView execute javascript within the loaded page?

Tags: ios, uiwebview

Can iOS UIWebView execute javascript contained in the loaded page?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, iOS UIWebView can execute JavaScript contained in the loaded page. (It can also execute JavaScript that you send to it through Objective-C code.)